# comparison of Date with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

I have an `age` method on my `Waiver` model that looks like:

```
  def age(date = nil)

    if date.nil?
      date = Date.today
    end
    age = 0
    unless date_of_birth.nil?
      age = date.year - date_of_birth.year
      age -= 1 if date < date_of_birth + age.years #for days before birthday
    end
    return age
  end
```

I then have a spec that looks like:

```
it "calculates the proper age" do
 waiver = FactoryGirl.create(:waiver, date_of_birth: 12.years.ago)
 waiver.age.should == 12
end
```

When I run this spec I get `comparison of Date with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Failures:

  1) Waiver calculates the proper age
     Failure/Error: waiver.age.should == 12
     ArgumentError:
       comparison of Date with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed
     # ./app/models/waiver.rb:132:in `<'
     # ./app/models/waiver.rb:132:in `age'
     # ./spec/models/waiver_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I don't know why it is failing but it is working fine if you set date_of_birth to `12.years.ago.to_date` and not `12.years.ago`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are comparing an instance of `Date` with an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` in the expression `date < date_of_birth + age.years`; ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone is, [according to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html), a Time-like class that can represent a time in any time zone. You simply can't compare `Date` and `Time` objects without performing some kind of conversion. Try `Date.today < Time.now` on a console; you'll see a similar error.

Expressions like `12.years.ago` and typical ActiveRecord timestamps are instances of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone. You are best off ensuring that you deal only with `Time` objects or `Date` objects, but not both in this method. To make your comparison date-to-date, the expression could instead be written as:

```
age -= 1 if date < (date_of_birth + age.years).to_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. I've made the appropriate changes to my code and everything is working great now!

Comment: actually, you can compare Date with TimeWithZone, but it seems Rails will convert Date to 00:00:00 UTC by default then, which might introduce bugs. Ie. >> `Time.zone.parse('Tue, 01 Aug 2017 00:00:00 CEST +02:00') < Date.new(2017,8,1)` => `true`